# Will there be any difference if I install Java from an RPM or just run the binary?

Tags: java, fedora

Would there be any technical differences if I installed Java from an RPM versus just running the available binary? I am running on CentOs 6.3 and Java is 1.7

Comment: Rpm is probably setting CLASSPATH for you, and binary won't. Inspect RPM to know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "technical differences" and "just running the available binary" but, no, there is no difference to running the bundled RPM version of the JRE/JKD from the exact same JRE/JDK, from the same manufacturer, for the same version, for the same platform and for the same architecture (32/64bit) from a downloaded TGZ.

An Operating System bundled JRE/JDK may have bundled extra libs, security configuration, certificates which may be different to a vanilla TGZ.

Comment: Oracle has two download links-- the RPM and the binary for "linux". They aren't distribution specific, merely "linux". Any differences between the two?

Comment: Nope, they should contain the same `java` binary executable and jars.